# Enabling and setting CORS in scriptr.io

Tags: javascript, cors

I'm trying to make a scriptr.io script to get data form Google+ API and return it to a RSS feed formated string.

I have a problem related to CORS when I try to run it.

> An error has occurred. This is most likely a cross-domain issue. In
>   case you modified the response object in your script, try adding
>   response.addHeaders(configuration.crossDomainHeaders) to your code.
>   You can refer to the documentation for more details.

I do add headers to my response however, I'm not sure how I should set it up in *Settings > Configuration > CORS*.

Here's my code so far.

```
var http = require("http");

try {
  // we retrieve the received json from request.parameters and we parse it since we know
  // it is a stringified json
  //var parameters = JSON.parse(request.parameters.params);
    var parameters = {
        googleApiKey: request.parameters.googleApiKey,
        googlePlusFeedURL: request.parameters.googlePlusFeedURL
    };
  var googleApiKey = parameters.googleApiKey;
    var googlePlusFeedURL = parameters.googlePlusFeedURL;

  // Prepare the request to send to Google Places API
  var requestParameters = {
    url: googlePlusFeedURL,
    params: {
      //fields: ["url","object(content,attachments/url)"],
      key: googleApiKey
    }
  };

  var rep = http.request(requestParameters);
  var body = JSON.parse(rep.body);
  var result = jsonToXml(body);

  response.write(result);

  // whenever you manipulate the response object make sure to add your CORS settings to the header
  console.log(configuration.crossDomainHeaders);
  response.addHeaders(configuration.crossDomainHeaders);
  response.close();
}    
catch (e) {
    return e;
}
```

Comment: is this server-side node.js? If so then tagging it might get you more attention from people with knowledge of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was following the documentation in the Response section. https://www.scriptr.io/documentation

I'm not sure why, but moving this line:

```
response.addHeaders(configuration.crossDomainHeaders);
```

Before this one:

```
response.write(result);
```

Got my code working.

Working code:

```
var http = require("http");

try {
  // we retrieve the received json from request.parameters and we parse it since we know
  // it is a stringified json
  //var parameters = JSON.parse(request.parameters.params);
    var parameters = {
        googleApiKey: request.parameters.googleApiKey,
        googlePlusFeedURL: request.parameters.googlePlusFeedURL
    };
  var googleApiKey = parameters.googleApiKey;
    var googlePlusFeedURL = parameters.googlePlusFeedURL;

  // Prepare the request to send to Google Places API
  var requestParameters = {
    url: googlePlusFeedURL,
    params: {
      //fields: ["url","object(content,attachments/url)"],
      key: googleApiKey
    }
  };

  var rep = http.request(requestParameters);
  var body = JSON.parse(rep.body);
  var result = jsonToXml(body);

  response.addHeaders(configuration.crossDomainHeaders);
  response.write(result);

  // whenever you manipulate the response object make sure to add your CORS settings to the header
  console.log(configuration.crossDomainHeaders);

  response.close();
}    
catch (e) {
    return e;
}
```